# MySQL - Count only if unique

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with object show/click statistics.
Table has such columns: id, objectId, pageUrl, event('show' or 'click').
For example:

```
id, objectId, pageUrl,  event  
1,    1,      /cars/,  show  
2,    1,      /cars/,  show  
3,    1,      /items/, show  
4,    2,      /cars/,  show  
5,    2,      /items/, show
```

Can I, in a simple way, get the count for each object having a unique pageUrl?

The result for dataset must be:

```
objectId, counter  
1,        2  
2,        2
```

For object with id 1 there are 3 records, but pageUrl /cars/ appears two times, so counter must be only for unique urls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT objectId, COUNT(DISTINCT(pageUrl)) AS 'counter'
FROM Table
GROUP BY objectId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT objectId, COUNT(*) AS count FROM ( SELECT objectId,pageUrl FROM table GROUP BY objectId,pageUrl ) z GROUP BY objectId
```

Comment: I suggest you to use aliases in order to avoid ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

You can use [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) and [count](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) like this:

```
SELECT count(distinct pageUrl) from object group by objectId
```

Comment: You also need to `SELECT` the `objectId` per the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah of course. I do assume OP knows how to select other columns. Just a little example. I see your answer has the result the OP wants. +1

Answer (score 0):

First, I generated the inner select query to group the records with the same `objectId` and `pageUrl`. Lastly, I counted the `pageURL` per `objectId`.

```
SELECT 
      objectId, 
      COUNT(pageUrl) 
FROM (SELECT objectId,pageUrl FROM table GROUP BY objectId,pageUrl) z 
GROUP BY objectId
```